# python 2.7.17 input error embedded '\0' in input line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to input something, but it shows this error:

> embedded '\0' in input line

```
klm=input("enter your name")
error
errortype=embedded '\0' in input line
```

And when I try:

```
klm=raw_input("enter your name")
```

there is error:

```
enter your nameMZ�       ��  �       @                                     � �  �!�L�!
This program cannot be run in DOS mode
```

Comment: You are running through interpreter right .??

Comment: Don' use `input` with Python 2. That is a mighty security breach for your application (in the background it does `eval` and we all know what that might do). And what did you enter when you used `raw_input`.

Comment: `input` in Python2 is not the same as `input` in Python3. Try `raw_input`

Comment: 1. Please post the full error message including stack trace. 2. Please let us know exactly where you run this program and how you're providing the input.

Comment: on pycharm 2019.2 by python 2.7.17

Comment: @matthiasa i inputed `klm=raw_input("what is your name:")`

Comment: I was not talking about the code. What did you type in when you ran the program and it asked for your name?

Comment: @matthias its automatically showed that

Comment: How did you start that code? From the command line? Have you perhaps tried to redirect (maybe automate) standard input?